# First order derivation with respect to a matrix

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I got stuck into solving the first differentiation of below equation with respect to Matrix A:
[\begin{array}{l}
{F =  { {{{\left( {{p^T}{A^T}\alpha  + \eta } \right)}^2}} }}
\end{array}

Where A is a matrix, p and $\alpha$ are vectors. A is $D \times D$, p and $\alpha$ are $D \times 1$. m, n, $\eta$ are scalars.

From a book I know that:
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{{\partial {a^T}{X^T}b}}{{\partial X}} = b{a^T}
\end{array}
Where X is matrix and a and b are vectors.

What is $\frac{ \partial F }{\partial A}$ ?

Any Attention is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear to me what is meant by "arg min_A". Are the scalars m,n and eta real or complex? If they are complex then what is the meaning of min_A?

Comment: It means that I want to minimize F with respect to matrix A. those scalars are real. Please just think the function without that arg min_A. I removed Arg min_A.

Comment: All right, I understand it now. Since the first term is non-negative you only have to minimize the second. In case mn is negative the minimum would be minus infinity (take for A a number times the identity matrix and let the number go to plus or minus infinity). In case mn>0 then you can equate the term in brackets to 0 and find A.

Comment: I want to solve it not analyze it.!

Comment: Yes, I understand that. You say that you want to minimize F. But for this you do not need derivatives wrt. A. It is sufficient to find an A for which (p^TA^Tα+η)^2=0 and that is a matter of some algebra.

Comment: Dear Urgie, as you told :In case mn>0 then you can equate the term in brackets to 0 and find A. Let me know what the solution will be.? I  couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The term containing $A$ can be rewritten as
$$
p^TA^Tα=trace(αp^TA^T)=trace(pα^TA)
$$
with derivative, as per your cited formula, of $pα^T$ or $αp^T$ depending on whether you use gradient or derivative conventions, i.e., if you consider
$$
\langle f'(A),H\rangle=trace(H^Tf'(A))=trace(f'(A)^TH)
$$
or
$$
f'(A)[H]=trace(f'(A)H)
$$
as formula for the directional derivative of some $f(A)$ in direction $H$, i.e., for $\tfrac{d}{dt}f(A+tH)|_{t=0}$.

---

Apart from that, it is just the chain rule for composite functions, and the outer function is univariate and scalar.

---

Without ever differentiating anything one can get the expression to zero. In extension to the procedure in the answer of Urgje, let $X$ be any matrix so that $λ=α^TXp\ne 0$, the set of admissible $X$ is the complement of a hyperplane in matrix space, so any random matrix will do with probability (close to) $1$. Then set $A=-\frac{η}{λ}X$ to get $F(A)=0$.

Comment: I can not figure out result based on A. I want to have optimal A.  I mean how can I have A= other terms ?

Comment: Well,then generate any random matrix $X$, compute $α^TXp$, if that is zero, chose another random matrix, and finally compute $A=-\frac{η}{α^TXp} X$. This makes, as Urgje already said, the whole expression zero, the lowest value a square can take. Or if you want a non-random matrix, take $X=αp^T$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the minimum of F by setting the derivative equal to 0 you also have to consider the second derivative since you want a minimum, not an inflection point. Since
$${\mathbf{p}}^{T}⋅{\mathbf{A}}^{T}⋅{\mathbf{α}}=p_{l}A_{lk}^{T}α_{k}=α_{k}A_{kl}p_{l}={\mathbf{α⋅A⋅p}}={\text{tr}}{\mathbf{pα⋅A}}=({\mathbf{pα,A}}),$$
where (,) is the inner product of two Schmidt class operators, the derivative can be defined as a Fréchet derivative (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frechet_derivative).

However, you do not need derivatives. Since the first term of F is non-negative, it is sufficient to minimize the second term. As I noted before, $mn$ must be non-negative and it is sufficient to find an ${\mathbf{A}}$ for which ${\mathbf{p^{T}⋅A^{T}⋅α}}+η={\mathbf{α⋅A⋅p}}+η=0$. Set ${\mathbf{A}}=λ{\mathbf{αp}}$. Then ${\mathbf{α⋅A⋅p}}+η=λα²p²+η=0$, so this term vanishes for $λ=-η/(α²p²)$. Other possible ${\mathbf{A}}$ are ${\mathbf{A}}=λ{\mathbf{(α+β)(p+q)}}$, where  ${\mathbf{β⊥α,q⊥p.}}$

Comment: m and n are positive. above is wrong, because, alpha is d times 1 and p also is d times 1. Then, it is impossible to multiply alpha*p.

Comment: I did not contract alpha and p. I used dyadic notation.

Comment: Thanks, but I can not figure out result based on A. I want to have optimal A.  I mean how can I have A= other terms ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \;\doteq\; {\rm Tr}(AB^T) $$
and for typing convenience, let's define the scalar
$$\eqalign{
\mu &= {p^T}{A^T}\alpha \\&= \alpha p^T:A \\d\mu &= \alpha p^T:dA \\
}$$
Now we can calculate the differential and gradient of the function as
$$\eqalign{
F &= (\mu+\eta)^2 \\
dF
 &= 2(\mu+\eta)\,d\mu \\
 &= 2(\mu+\eta)\,(\alpha p^T):dA \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial A}
 &= 2(\mu+\eta)\,(\alpha p^T) \\
}$$
As noted elsewhere, setting
$$A = -\left(\frac{\eta X}{p^TX^T\alpha}\right)$$
yields a gradient of zero, for any matrix $X$ for which the denominator is non-zero.
A particularly simple choice is the rank-one matrix
$$X = \alpha p^T$$